# External API for changing content in TYPO3

Tags: rest, http, typo3

Since I only have Editor permissions on our TYPO3 instance and can't install any code myself, I would like to generate content on an external server and change it on the TYPO3 instance.

Is it possible to edit a content element in TYPO3 through some kind of HTTP API without having to scrapt the user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no external content API.